# How to replenish only electrolytes during long distance running

Tags: running, nutrition, long-distance-running, endurance

As an endurance runner, I have long runs both on Saturdays and Sundays. So far I drink either water or Gatorade. If I drink only water on a 2-4 hour run, that is supposed to burn some fat. However, I would still like to compensate for the loss of electrolytes without taking in all those calories from Gatorade.

What would you recommend? I am somewhat experienced, completed more than 20 marathons and ultras. I am not very much concerned with speed at this time, but I would rather lose some weight.

Comment: Why do you want to "compensate for the loss of electrolytes". [What *are* these electrolytes? Do you even know?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e1fKzw05Q5A)

Comment: Check out hammer nutrition's endurolytes. They're popular in the cycling/triathlon community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard of people who train their bodies to work better burning fat on long runs by running without a sports drink. However, the fat burning metabolic system produces energy at a much slower rate than the sugar burning one. This is where 'the wall' cones from.

The suggestion above to use electrolyte drink is a good one. You could also consider supplementing with salt capsules. Thermolyte and S-Caps are two brands I know.

For sufficiently long runs in sufficiently warm weather you definitely want to do this. As you sweat and as your muscles burn you will lose sodium, potassium, magnesium and calcium.

You need sodium and potassium to be balanced as you sweat them out. The concentration in your blood needs to be within a narrow range else you run the risk of such deadly conditions as hyponatremia.

Calcium and magnesium are used by your muscles to signal contractions. If you run out then you will cramp.

This is why electrolyte drinks and salt tabs have this 4 minerals. The magnesium and calcium will be a much smaller amount than the other two.

When you use a salt tab be very sure to take it with lots of water. They are concentrated enough that if they dissolve by themselves in your stomach then your stomach will detect this and you will throw up. I've done this twice!

[Karl King's water/electrolyte balance table](http://www.succeedscaps.com/articles/water_electrolyte_balance_table/) is a very valuable resource to have on hand because it helps tell the difference between a number of conditions and what action to take.

[Statement of the Second International Exercise-Associated Hyponatremia Consensus Development Conference, New Zealand, 2007.](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/5518929_Statement_of_the_Second_International_Exercise-Associated_Hyponatremia_Consensus_Development_Conference_New_Zealand_2007?ev=prf_cit)
 is a great source for the raw science.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running that far/long, I wouldn't be concerned with the calories from gatorade as much I would be the quantity and quality of calories from the rest of my diet. Looking at the nutrition of a [bulk gatorade powder](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0052HV6EU), a 20oz has about 134 calories in it, and @ 34g of sugar those calories are pretty much all from sugar. However, from experience, all electrolyte replenishers I've seen on the market have a high sugar content, probably to hide the [saltiness of electrolytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrolyte). I'd be interested to know of any on the market that don't.

Marathon running will burn *calories*, not necessarily fat, at least not fat alone. It will burn calories whether you drink water or gatorade or anything else, to lose weight you require a calorie deficit. There are other questions on the site that breakdown steady state cardio and what it does for weight loss, so I'll point you here!

Comment: +1:  Running for 2-4 hours will expend a LOT more calories than you would consume by drinking a sufficient amount of Gatorade needed to maintain electrolytic balance.  One hour of jogging will typically burn about 600-900 kcal, depending on body weight; full running uses even more, 800-1200 kcal.  You won't need to drink ten 20-oz. bottles of Gatorade per hour to avoid dehydration.

Answer (score 1):

A study on Ironman triathletes found that supplementing sodium during a triathlon had no real effect on blood sodium. ([source](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16505084))

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of brands of electrolyte drinks without many calories or sugar. Most of these are in the form of tablets, which dissolve in water.
Some examples:

- [Nuun](http://www.nuun.com) - 8 calories per 500ml
- High Five Zero - zero calories
- SIS Go Hydro - 7 calories per 500ml

There is also bulk electrolyte powder available. This is usually cheaper than tablets, but it means you have to measure it out yourself. And it may not dissolve as well in water. eg [My Protein Electrolyte powder](http://www.myprotein.com/sports-nutrition/electrolyte-powder/10529892.html).